# I need help on chaining nested functions without changing the format

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I tried nesting function but i cannot receive it in the next functions
result return `this.a is undefined` in the remaining function one and two
but i dont want to change the format

```js
const All = function () {
  this.obj = (a, b) => {
    this.a = a;
    return this;
  };
  this.one = () => {
    console.log(this.a); //this.a is un-defined here
    return this;
  };
  this.two = () => {
    console.log(this.a); //this.a is un-defined here
    return this;
  };
};

const all = new All();


all.obj({
  1: all.one().two(),
});
```

Comment: Looks like you never defined an `obj` method, hence the error

Comment: `all.one().two()` you don't pass `a` in `one`, so `this.a` is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: Remember: What is nested inside is executed first (exeption: nested code that is to be compiled). So `all.one().two()` is executed first, and then `all.obj()` is executed. From where should `one()` and `two()` know the definition of `a`, if they are called first?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning `undefined` to `this.a`. Try:

```js
const All = function() {
  this.one = (a, b) => {
    this.a = a;
    return this;
  };
  this.two = () => {
    console.log(this.a); //this.a is un-defined here
    return this;
  };
  this.three = () => {
    console.log(this.a); //this.a is un-defined here
    return this;
  };
};

const all = new All();


all.one(1).two()
```